# filter lazy initialised collection

Tags: java, hibernate, hql, cartesian-product

I am having some performance issues due to some HQL queries resulting in large Cartesian Products. To get around this I'm trying to lazy fetch the collections although I cant find a nice way of applying a where clause to resulting collections.

Simplified version of the original HQL query

```
SELECT TPR 
FROM TacticalPriceRule
INNER JOIN FETCH TPR.tacticalPriceRuleDurations TPRD
LEFT JOIN FETCH TPR.tacticalPriceRuleCountryOfOrigins as TPRCOO  
LEFT JOIN FETCH TPR.tacticalPriceRuleType as TPRT  
LEFT JOIN FETCH TPR.tacticalPriceRuleCars as TPRC  
WHERE
     TPRD.duration.min <= :duration and TPRD.duration.max >= :duration
     .... more conditions on other joins
```

This results in nearly nearly 1 million rows for a few tiny tables. Not ideal.

If I attempt to do this using lazy initialisation, any 'where' or 'with' clauses are ignored and the entire sets matching the tactical price rule is contained within the collection.

Same applies for subselect fetch types.

Thanks,

Dan

Comment: Can you give us the SQL Hibernate executes? It might contain some valuable information

Comment: That's expected. An entity is supposed to contain the state in the database. Not the result of some specific query where part of the state is filtered out. BTW, inner join fetches and conditions on fetched entities are forbidden, for this reason, in the JPA specification (which Hibernate doesn't respect here). You could select only the values you're interested into, or you could execute several queries with different select clauses but similar where clauses.

Comment: Jeroen, the SQL behind this is pretty much as it is in HQL.

Comment: JB, thats understandable although would you really expect the business logic to be responsible for iterating and searching through large collections which are only required to contain a couple of values? I was trying to avoid populating the collections manually with selects.